# How to plot Bubble chart with plots outside axis area using Excel

Tags: excel, macos, ms-office, bubble-chart

Im using Excel for Mac 2011 and I have the following figure

[image]

I would like to still show the bubbles outside of the available chart area, while keeping the maximum and minimum axes values unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an identical chart with the same data, but with axis limits that show the full bubbles. Then set all the formatting in the chart other than the bubbles to the equivalent of "none", i.e, no  axis labels, chart outlines, gridlines, chart and plot borders, background color, etc.

With very careful sizing and positioning of this bubbles-only chart over the original chart, you can get the bubbles to extend beyond the plot area of the original. If the size or position of a bubble is a little off, modify the overlay chart's data by the tiny amount needed to get the bubble to cover the underlying original bubble. Turn off the formatting for the underlying bubbles as last step.

NOT programmatic, very trial and error, and fussy, of course, and I hope someone comes up with a more elegant way to achieve your goal. But I was able to get it to work on my Windows machine.